# Confusing regarding triangular wave vs square wave?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, fourier, terminology, approximation, square

I am reading signal processing first by Mcclellan. In chapter 3, I came across the term "discontinous" as shown underlined in attached photo.

Apparently "discontinuous" means having a gap/break but in attached photo we see square wave is mentioned as discontinuous while triangular wave is mentioned as continuous, although there isn't any apparent gap/break in both graphs.

What is the reason for this difference? In context of dsp?

[image]

Comment: as said below your last quesion on "discontinuous signals", the term is mathematically well-defined, and I linked to that definition. I'm not really sure what this near-identical question is about now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Ideal) square waves are often drawn in a misleading way, because the vertical lines don't actually represent a signal value. The square wave actually jumps instantanously between two values, creating a discontinuity.

In other words, a function that is defined like this:
$$f(t) = \begin{cases} 0\,\,\,t<0\\1\,\,\,t>=0\end{cases}$$ is discontinuous. Even if you draw a vertical line from 0 to 1 at $t=0$, the vertical line does not actually represent the function: $f(t)$ is *never* 0.5, or 0.3, or anything besides 0 and 1. Mathematically, the function has a different value when $t$ approaches 0 from the left ($t$ increasing from $-\infty$ to 0) than when approached from the right ($t$ decreasing from $\infty$ to 0).

The triangular wave does not suffer from this problem (but note that its derivative *is* discontinuous). Mathematically, whether you approach the peak from the left or from the right, you reach the same value.

Comment: So in a nutshell you mean, to be continous a graph of signal must take or pass through all values between two levels(1 and 0) .? Graph cannot change immediately from 0 to 1 or vice versa for continuous signal?

Comment: @Man That's right.

Comment: One more concept, if you can kindly guide me comfortably?what is the effect of sudden/abrupt change in amplitude (such as in unit step and square wave) on frequency spectrum?

Comment: Any instantaneous change in amplitude implies that the spectrum extends to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Spectrum extends only to plus infinity or negative infinity or both?

Comment: @Man I meant what I said: both.

Comment: Ok thank you so much